# HomeBrew Errors for PHP

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Did a brew update, then brew doctor in my terminal. Running MAC OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

Getting error message, 
Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

```
 Unexpected .la files:
 /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.la

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

mhash
```

I've tried brew link --overwrite mhash but it comes back to me

```
  Error: Could not symlink include/mutils/mglobal.h
/usr/local/include/mutils is not writable.
```

I've also tried sudo brew link --overwrite mcrypt but that doesn't work either. Not sure what to do.

Comment: If a directory is not writable as SUDO then the directory needs write permissions all together Try  `sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/include/mutils.` **NOTE** Take note of the permissions before making this adjustment, and reset them when you're done.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried that, and afterwards ran brew link mhash and got this. Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    mhash
brew link mhash
~$ brew link mhash
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mhash/0.9.9.9... 
Error: Could not symlink include/mutils/mglobal.h
/usr/local/include/mutils is not writable.